# Magento 2.1 magemonkey install extension failed

Tags: magento-2.1, php, module

For the last couple of days I cannot install any extension on live server. The problems that I am having:

Web setup wizard is not showing. Found a workaround to access it via /admin/backend/setup ... only to say Upgrad already in progress and it is like that forever, no clue what is going on.

Tried to install it manually following the tutorials on web.

- Step 1: Download/purchase the extension
- Step 2: Unzip the file in a temporary directory
- Step 3: Upload it to your Magento installation root directory
- Step 4: Disable the cache under System­ >> Cache Management
- Step 5: Enter the following at the command line:
- php ­f bin/magento setup:upgrade

So I did it.

- I unzipped the file and get ebizmarts-magento2-magemonkey-3.0.7 folder.
- I copy that folder in my public_html/magento/ folder (magento root folder). So now i got ebizmarts-magento2-magemonkey-3.0.7 inside my root magento.
- php ­f bin/magento setup:upgrade, also tried static content deploy, and nothing.

I can install this extension via composer on my localhost, but I can't manually. On my live server I need to install it manually.

I am guessing that all tutorials on the web are missing some steps. Do I need to follow some naming convention. Some say that I should copy that folder in pub/code. What am I missing?

Comment: same as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351544/magento-2-1-manuall-install-extensions-wont-work/44421407#44421407

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

- don't copy the folder to your Magento2-directory, copy the *contents* of the folder. Inside, there should be a folder structure either `app/code/Ebiszmarts/...` or `vendor/ebizmarts/...`. This folders should integrate with your Magento 2 installation
- after that, first run `php bin/magento module:enable Ebizmarts_Magemonkey` (assuming this is the module identifier) before you run `setup:upgrade`